# unresolved reference: Callback

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to port my android project to Kotlin, but faced problem with retrofit2.Callback. Even if I import this interface I keep receiving `Unresolved reference: Callback` error.

Why could this happen and how could I fix it?

Comment: Please add the full error description including the relevant piece of code.

Comment: Try to create a concrete implementation of retrofit2.Callback interface and use one:

    class MyCallback2 : Callback<String> {
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>?, t: Throwable?) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
    
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>?, response:     Response<String>?) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
        }
    }

Comment: Or you can make so:

call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<String> {...})

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @cVoronin's answer:

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable?) {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
        // TODO implement me
    }
})
```

Note on `response` from Retrofit2 [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html):

> An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500. Call Response.isSuccessful() to determine if the response indicates success.

Comment: please i have did that i got the same error, please how can i fix it. Here is the complete link to the issue that i got :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040797/kotlin-retrofit2-how-to-convert-enqueue-and-callback-from-java-to-kotlin